# How to count rows of one byte array every 16 bytes?

Tags: c#

I need to count the number of rows in a byte array every 16 bytes.
I get the line number with a method that before, converts the array to string.
However, this conversion of the array into a string whenever it counts, is greatly overloading the process.
So I was wondering, how to get the number of rows in a byte array every 16 bytes, but without this conversion to string.
Do you have any ideas?

```
    string hexString = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer);
    int lineCount = CountLinesHexString(hexString); //Sum 32 in 32 characters (16 Bytes).
    int expectedLength = lineCount * 16;

    public static int CountLinesHexString(string hexStringToCount)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@".{32}");
        string hexStringLinesOf16 = regex.Replace(hexStringToCount, "$&" + Environment.NewLine);
        int length = hexStringLinesOf16.Length;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (hexStringLinesOf16[i] == '\n') count++;
        }
        return count + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i understood your question there is no need to conversion to string just do this:

```
int bufferLength=buffer.Length;

int lineCount=(bufferLength + 15) / 16;
```

all done

Thanks for comment

Comment: You mean `Length` rather than `Length()`, and unless the OP knows that there will always be a multiple of 16 bytes, you probably want `(bufferLength + 15) / 16` to round up.